# Formal definitions of Classes and Structs

Tags: math, class, object, struct

I remember touching on this subject during a class on programming languages. I vaguely remember that a struct could be seen as a mathematical tuple.  Is it possible to describe a class or an object in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. See ["A Theory of Objects" by Abadi and Cardelli](http://lucacardelli.name/TheoryOfObjects.html).